# where do i get drivers for my Lenovo Ideatab a3000-h?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, lenovo

I need to back-up my tablet...where do i get the drivers for it?
Its a Lenovo Ideatab A3000-H 
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

When i plug my tablet into my laptop, I can't see it, so i assume i need the drivers for it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dude, Just plug it in as a media device and you can easily explore the whole SD card of your tab on PC. I faced the same prob with tab, but it works when i used it as media device(MTP)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need drivers to access the files on it. What happens when you plug it in? It should show up on your desktop or in your file browser.

Comment: Its plugged in, in media device form. when i change it to ESB tether i still don't see it in my file browser?